# Авто-размер фото

Tags: html, css

У меня такой вопрос как сделать чтобы каждое фото в сайте адаптировалась с помощью блоков вот например как на скриншоте как бы например в инстаргаме любое фото адапитруется с помощью div я подумал с помощью боотсрап там только ширина а высота я не пойму..[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно приложить код html и css, без этого трудно понять каким именно образом формируется сетка. Также следует сказать, будут ли все фотографии с квадратным соотношением сторон или нет.

Comment: вот да квадратные как видите на изображении а какой html css? Вы примерно можете написать код который может вот так как на изображении определить размер

Comment: Вы хотите резиновую вёрстку или чтобы блоки были примерно всегда одного размера, но перемещались по странице?

Comment: да вот например говорю блок див 10х10 а фото например 100х100 хочу чтобы автоматически стало 10х10(размер блока) без деформации т.д как на инстаграм посмотрите пойметеменя

Comment: @SportsTubers, может просто для div'ов делать `background-image: url(...); background-size: cover;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать абсолютное позиционирование изображения относительно контейнера. То есть ширину задавать на весь размер контейнера через width: 100%, высота, как известно, установиться пропорционально. И после этого установить верхнюю позицию изображения как top: 50%. А дальше используем правило transform: translateY(-50%). Благодаря этому изображение впишется по высоте в контейнер. Естественно, у контейнера нужно указать свойство overflow: hidden, чтобы скрыть выходящие за его края части изображения.

```css
.gallery picture {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

.gallery img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <picture>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x220" />
  </picture>
  <picture>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/220x250" />
  </picture>
</div>
```

В примере видно, что размеры картинок подгружаются разные, но благодаря стилям они масштабируются и вписываются в контейнер по вертикали.

Comment: Я щас попробую спасибо вам за труд

Comment: Блогадарю вас! Отличный код именно по душе очень блогадарю!

Comment: Можно вас еще кое что спросить?

Comment: Можно, спрашивайте.

Answer (score 1):

Можно пихать изображение в блок с помощью background-image, а ресайзить с помощью background-size: cover или contain

Comment: Можно и такой метод использовать. Будет работать.

Comment: Я попробую щас.

Answer (score 0):

Например:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div><img src="w.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="w.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="w.jpg"></div>
  <div><img src="w.jpg"></div>
</div>    

<style>
  .wrap>div {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
  }
  .wrap img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>
```

Картинки будут помещены в блоки и будут резиново изменяться вместе с ними

Comment: Крайне неудачный пример. Ведь изображения просто будут "плющиться". В общем, будет некрасиво.

Comment: Они не будут плющится, они буду изменять масштаб. Этот пример соответствует вопросу автора.

Comment: Если предположить, что пропорции сторон изображений не соответствуют пропорциям контейнера, то, например, прямоугольная картинка при вписывании в квадратный контейнер будет искажена сжатием. Ведь задавая ширину и высоту жестко в 100% мы фактически приводим изображение к пропорциям контейнера. Поэтому стопроцентно ее сплющит.

Comment: В соответствии с ТЗ автора: картинки квадратные, контейнеры квадратные. Прочитайте сообщения выше, там есть описание того, что требуется.

Comment: Полагаю, что автор вопроса не испытывал бы проблемы, если бы картинки были изначально квадратными. Тогда достаточно было изменять одну лишь ширину, а высота изменилась бы пропорционально. Но поскольку автор упоминает слово "деформация", то это как раз и обозначает проблему - изображения не вписываются в квадратный контейнер. Смею предположить, что изображения-то как раз у него не квадратные. Иначе и проблемы бы не возникало.

Comment: "да вот например говорю блок див 10х10 а фото например 100х100 хочу чтобы автоматически стало 10х10(размер блока) без деформации т.д как на инстаграм посмотрите пойметеменя"

Comment: Как бы там не было, Ваш пример просто вписывает картинку в контейнер. И если предположить, что исходные картинки квадратные, то задание высоты является просто излишним. Хотелось бы сейчас услышать самого автора вопроса. Вам вписать или обрезать?

Comment: Олег Солдатов прав я сам тоже сделал так как вы фото 100х800 например ужасно выглядело именно вот этот "плющиться" а я хочу чтобы вот задать див и все картинки отобразились нормально в див самый лучший пример это инстаграм. думаю поняли меня

Comment: Вам тоже я блогадарен очень ценю это но немного код Олег Солдатова мне понравилось больше блогадарю вас за ваш труд тоже!

Answer (score 0):

Для начала необходимо при загрузке изображения сделать миниатюру, чтобы ширина и высота были одинаковы. Это необходимо для сохранения качества изображения.

Далее CSS. Используйте media запросы и регулируйте размер изображения для каждого типа устройства.